# Get a particular day from a range of dates using oracle

Tags: oracle

I want to get a Monday/any particular day from a range of days. The range of days is always a week.

**Example:** The week is 12/13/2014 - 12/19/2014. If I want to get a Monday/Tuesday from this range, how do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use function NEXT_DAY, for example:

```
next_day('12/13/2014','MONDAY')
```

Give you next Monday.

```
next_day('12/13/2014','TUESDAY')
```

Give you next Tuesday.